# Using a CDN to serve Images from the wordpress Shopp plugin

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, cdn, shopp

I am using a CDN with my shopp installation. I used super cache to do most of the setup for getting my content on the cdn. However, the images that are served by the database (product images) are not being pulled from the cdn. I did check that they exist on the cdn.

i know that you need to do something to the htaccess file and this is what i got so far

`RewriteEngine On`

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^.shop/images/(\d+)/?\??(.)$ http://cdn.example.com/shop/images/$1/?$2 [L,R=301]

but it doesn't seem to work. anyone know a solution?

Comment: sorry forgot some details

images from shopp are being pulled in the format
http://example.com/shop/images/73/?280,340,667194571

and the files in the format
http://cdn.example.com/shop/images/73/?280,340,667194571

exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query String (everything after `?`) cannot be matched in RewriteRule directive.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^shop/images/(\d+)/ http://cdn.example.com/shop/images/$1/ [NC,QSA,R=301]
```

The above rule only matches URL, the query string (e.g. `?280,340,667194571`) will be passed as is (no additional checks -- what for?). As long as URL is in this format `shop/images/{some_digits_only}/` (e.g. `example.com/shop/images/73/`) it will issue **Permanent** redirect (301) and URL in browser will be changed to CDN URL (e.g. `http://cdn.example.com/shop/images/73/?280,340,667194571`).